# Heroku RedisCloud Redis::CannotConnectError on localhost instead of REDISCLOUD_URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, redis

There are quite a few questions like this, but none seem to resolve my issue. Here's the grub:

Rails 4, Ruby 2.0.0 app using Resque and Redis.

My redis initializer:

```
#config/initializers/redis.rb
if ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]
    $redis = Redis.new(:url => ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"])
end
```

Error is this, as reported by heroku logs:

```
Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)
```

My procfile:

```
web: bundle exec rackup config.ru -p $PORT
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 QUEUES=* bundle exec rake resque:work
```

If it helps, my `REDISCLOUD_URL` is:

```
redis://rediscloud:somestuff@someotherstuff:17695
```

It isn't in `http://`. Is that an issue?

I've tried all the other stack overflow posts on this issues, and nothing works. Any tips? I've been follwing the RedisCloud Heroku page here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rediscloud

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer. I did `$redis = Resque.redis = Redis.new ...` in my redis.rb initializer, and then I had to migrate my db. Silly me.

Comment: Yeah, worked for me too. There seems to be an error in the documentation at heroku. I'll write them

Comment: Ah.. You write what you have done, but is actually the right answer?